# Plotting a polar rose — how to use "n" and "d" to achieve different shapes?

Tags: algorithm, math, pascal

In code form, the calculation of the coordinates of the polar rose point in the Cartesian system can be represented as follows:

```pascal
X := OriginX + A * Cos(K * Theta) * Cos(Theta);
Y := OriginY + A * Cos(K * Theta) * Sin(Theta);
```

| Parameter | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `OriginX` | the `X` coordinate of the rose's center point |
| `OriginY` | the `Y` coordinate of the rose's center point |
| `A` | target rose radius |
| `K` | angular frequency |

The above code works prefectly. For example, setting `K` as `5`, I get a flower with five petals. For other positive integer values of `K` I also get correct flowers, consistent with the first row of those given on Wikipedia:

[image]
Image credit: Jason Davies via [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Rose-rhodonea-curve-7x9-chart-improved.svg).

Now I would like my code to be able to generate roses from other rows. I found the article [Polar rose garden](https://blog.k2h.se/post/polar-rose-garden/) and there is a image with various roses, where `k` is integer or real:

https://blog.k2h.se/post/2020-01-03-polar-rose-garden_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-2-1.png

For example, for `k = 1 / 3`, the rose should look like this:

Also https://blog.k2h.se/post/2020-01-03-polar-rose-garden_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-2-1.png look for caption `1/3`.

but if I use the following code:

```pascal
var
  Theta:   Single;
  OriginX: Integer;
  OriginY: Integer;
  Size:    Integer;
  X:       Integer;
  Y:       Integer;
  K:       Single;
begin
  OriginX := 120;
  OriginY := 120;
  Size    := 120;
  K       := 1 / 3;
  Theta   := 0.0;

  while Theta < Pi * 2 do
  begin
    X := Round(OriginX + Size * Cos(K * Theta) * Cos(Theta));
    Y := Round(OriginY + Size * Cos(K * Theta) * Sin(Theta));

    Canvas.Pixels[X, Y] := clGray;

    Theta += 0.001;
  end;
end;
```

the rose looks like this:

[image]

Could anyone advise why my graph is broken?

PS: I'm not a mathematician, so C/Pascal code would be perfect.

Comment: You could experiment with the expressions given by Wikipedia to see what the effects of `n` and `d` are.

Comment: The thing is that I don't know where to add these parameters `n` and `d`. I edited the post and added information from someone's blog in which `k = n / d`, but this gives bad result — graph is not full.

Comment: `k = n / d` is correct. Re "*Could anyone advise how to modify my code*", How could we possibly do that since you didn't show it? We can't show the error in your code if you don't provide it!

Comment: You can reduce the fraction n/d to its simplest form by dividing n and d by their greatest common divisor (use the Euclidean algorithm to find the greatest common divisor of n and d). Then replace n and d by their reduced form, and plot for values of theta between 0 and 2*pi*d.

Comment: Ok, I added a loop rendering the test rose. Everything seems to be fine and yet I only get the bottom half of the output. Something is wrong.

Comment: Plot looks fine for `k = 1 / 3` and the loop `while Theta < 4 * Pi`. I can't figure out why I have to use `4 * Pi` instead of `2 * Pi` (for `k = 5`).

Comment: I checked - `n * d * pi` gives an incorrect graph for `k` being a non-integer value, graph is not complete.

Comment: I found that for non-integer `k`, upper bound of `Theta` must be greater than `2 * Pi`. For example, if `k = 1 / 3`, the upper `Theta` bound must be `4 * Pi`. I can't figure out what is the formula to calculate the `Theta` upper bound.

Comment: After some experimentation with different values of n / d reduced to its simplest form (e.g. replacing 4 / 6 with 2 / 3), plotting for theta in the range 0 to (1 + ((n + d) mod 2)) * d * pi seems to suffice.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. But there is a problem — some graphs are rendered multiple times, for example for `k=3/3`, `k=3/6`, `k=3/9`, `k=5/10`, `k=6/3` and so on. This is a problem because if I use polar rose formula to calculate trajectory, the animation will work too fast for these cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't just blindly run from 0 to 2PI, because that doesn't guarantee a full period of the graph. After all, we're not working with `cos(theta)` and `sin(theta)`, we're working with an additional factor `cos(n/d * theta)`, so we'll need to *at the very least* multiply by **d** in order to get back to full periods, but **n** is a bit sneaky here.

If we turn to [the Wikipedia page for rose curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:PermaLink/1187918118#Roses_with_rational_number_values_for_k), specifically the section for when **k** is rational, we learn that:

> In the case when **both n and d are odd**, the positive and negative half-cycles of the sinusoid are coincident. The graph of these roses are completed in any continuous interval of polar angles that is **dπ** long.
>
> When **n is even and d is odd, or visa versa**, the rose will be completely graphed in a continuous polar angle interval **2dπ** long

So a modulo-based check should do:

```html
<script type="module" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/graphics-element/1.11.1/graphics-element.js" integrity="sha512-fz6xdkeMImCEkyHV+HPpg7C9cxoqc0w9RdSzm9ufj2wjFQFz71iJvyazoM9tXRGBzN40GuNY2e5fmimRiBFoJw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/graphics-element/1.11.1/graphics-element.css" integrity="sha512-sD4sJLVEBRXXbNNaSs/vwyt6vgq+jIiAhpg1MtqNdmhOt3k6K7V4wH5p5IxNvRXAoP51rAHyig0f4egsM+WdCQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<graphics-element id="graphics" width="200px" height="160px" title="let's draw some roses">
  <graphics-source>
    const r = 70;
    let k = 1;

    function setup() {
      addSlider(`n`, {min:1, max:7, step:1, value:1 });
      addSlider(`d`, {min:1, max:9, step:1, value:3 });
    }
    
    function draw() {
      k = n / d;
      clear();
      noFill();
      translate(width/2, height/2);

      // what's our  "loop limit"?
      const oddN = (n % 2) === 1;
      const oddD = (d % 2) === 1;
      const limit = d * ((oddN && oddD) ? PI : TAU);

      // let's draw!
      start();
      for (let theta = 0, f, x, y; theta <= limit; theta += 0.001) {
        f = r * cos(k * theta);
        x = f * cos(theta);
        y = f * sin(theta);
        vertex(x, y);
     }
     end();
    }
  </graphics-source>
</graphics-element>
```

The last time I've used Pascal was probably 40 years ago, so you'll have to "port" that solution yourself, but that should be pretty easy =)

Comment: Thank you! This is nice approach but for some cases the rose is rendered multiple times (at least twice) what is clearly visible in the snippet (graph line is thicker).

Comment: It has to: there are always `n` petals, but depending on `d`, those petals may overlap. (Most notably, of course, when `n` is equal to `d`)

Comment: So it looks like it may be impossible to define a single formula for calculating the upper bound of `theta`, for any `n` and `d`, so that the graph renders once. In some cases the upper bound must be manually adjusted. Thanks for help anyway. ;)

Comment: There might be, but as a "pure math" question (an interesting one though!) I would recommend asking about that over on the [math.se] stackexchange instead.

Comment: The solution to the problem turns out to be trivial — if the parameters `n` and `d` form a shortenable fraction, you need to reduce the fraction before using these parameters to plot a graph. And that's it — the graph will always be complete and always only one rose cycle will be rendered. :)

Comment: Nice! Update the answer for that, too.